# nunjucks fetch data from input

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

I am trying to retrieve below field values in nunjucks following below template
Json data -

```
{
    "user": {
        "custom": [
            {
                "payload": "{ f_name=user, l_name=name, source=facebook, contact=email }"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Nunjucks Template -

```
{% set u = user %}
{% set data = u['custom'][0]['payload'] %}

Hello {{ data }}
```

This returns the below output

```
Hello { f_name=user, l_name=name, source=facebook, contact=email }
```

However, I would like to get the individual elements from the `{{data}}`
How can I fetch the `f_name`, `l_name`, `source`, `contact` fields from the above json data.
Please note the payload is a `string` and not a json object

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us how `user` is pulling your JSON data into nunjucks, so I'll just spill out my take on this. Take advantage of the [JavaScript split method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), and the [template engine loops and filters](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#builtin-filter) to give you the results you need.

I'm assuming there is more to your JSON data. If so, here is a short guide to help pull your 4 string items out of payload.

The JSON Data:

```json
    //sample JSON Data
    const sampleData = [{
            "user": {
                "custom": [{
                    "payload": "{ f_name=user, l_name=name, source=facebook, contact=email }"
                }]
            }
        }];
    
    module.exports = sampleData;
```

The View:

```
{% for string in mSampleData %} //mSampleData is similar to your "user" template object.
  {% for mval in string['user']['custom'] %}
        {% set mstring = mval['payload'].replace('{', '').replace('}', '') %}
        {% set marray  = mstring.split(",") %}
        {% set fname   = marray[0].replace('f_name=', '') %}
        {% set lname   = marray[1].replace('l_name=','') %}
        {% set source  = marray[2].replace('source=','') %}
        {% set contact = marray[3].replace('contact=','') %}

        <p>{{fname}}</p>
        <p>{{lname}}</p>
        <p>{{source}}</p>
        <p>{{contact}}</p>

  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The results:

```
user
name
facebook
email
```